# Ctrl+E,D doesn't work anymore in Visual Studio 2008 ?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have been using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>D</kbd> to arrange my codes in VS 2008 (C#),
Some days ago I installed a C# component, since then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>D</kbd> doesn't work anymore!

How I can fix it so it works again?

Comment: Which C# component, if it seems linked to that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can customise the Autoformat key chord.

```
Tools, Customise, "Keyboard..."
```

Then enter customise "Edit.FormatSelection" for the default editor scheme;

[image: Options dialogue]

Answer (score 2):

To restore the old keyboard mapping, go to Options->Environment->Keyboard->Apply the following additional keyboard mapping scheme and choose Visual C# 2005

Answer (score 0):

Auto formatting?

```
Ctrl+K,Ctrl+F
```

Or

```
Edit -> Advanced -> Format Selection
```

Comment: Thanks, What about Ctrl+E,D . How can I restore it ?
because I accustomed to it ;)

Comment: Tools, Customise, Keyboard, select default scheme, enter "Edit.FormatSelection", add shortcut key. I'll add another answer with a picture ^^